# Glitches on curves when importing svg

Tags: modifiers, bezier-curves, subdivision-surface, artifacts, svg

I have a curve with the following modifiers added:

- Mirror
- Solidify
- Subdivision

And I keep getting these glitches.

If I remove the subdivision modifier then the glitches disappear.

I sometimes get these issues when adding `solidify`, but can normally fix it by going into edit mode, selecting the vertex, and pressing `v` and then playing about with the different options.

But that doesnt seem to be working in this case because of the subdivisions

[image]

[image]